# Error con el método show de librería Calendar

Tags: android

Utilizando la siguiente librería: https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker me estoy copiando el código de prueba en mi proyecto. Tuve que cambiar la manera de llamar el método show por ciertos errores... ahora que sí compila el proyecto me da error al darle click al botón que ejecuta el método show:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.dedicables.videos.dedicable, PID: 2397
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1345)
>   at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:597)
>   at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575) at
>   android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230) at
>   com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.Calendar$2.onClick(Calendar.java:190)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Donde la línea 192 de la clase Calendar es:

```
dpd.show(new Activity().getFragmentManager(),"Etiqueta");
```

Aquí está mi clase completa:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.rest.Model.Sex;
import com.dedicables.videos.dedicable.rest.Services.sexService;
import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.Utils;
import com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.RadialPickerLayout;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

/**
 * Created by Principal on 03/06/2016.
 */
public class Calendar extends Fragment  implements
    com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener,
    com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{


private static Context context;

private TextView timeTextView;
private TextView dateTextView;
private CheckBox mode24Hours;
private CheckBox modeDarkTime;
private CheckBox modeDarkDate;
private CheckBox modeCustomAccentTime;
private CheckBox modeCustomAccentDate;
private CheckBox vibrateTime;
private CheckBox vibrateDate;
private CheckBox dismissTime;
private CheckBox dismissDate;
private CheckBox titleTime;
private CheckBox titleDate;
private CheckBox showYearFirst;
private CheckBox enableSeconds;
private CheckBox limitTimes;
private CheckBox limitDates;
private CheckBox highlightDates;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}



@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fm_calendar, container, false);


    // Find our View instances
    timeTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.time_textview);
    dateTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
    Button timeButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.time_button);
    Button dateButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.date_button);
    mode24Hours = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.mode_24_hours);
    modeDarkTime = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.mode_dark_time);
    modeDarkDate = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.mode_dark_date);
    modeCustomAccentTime = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mode_custom_accent_time);
    modeCustomAccentDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mode_custom_accent_date);
    vibrateTime = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.vibrate_time);
    vibrateDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.vibrate_date);
    dismissTime = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.dismiss_time);
    dismissDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.dismiss_date);
    titleTime = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.title_time);
    titleDate = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.title_date);
    showYearFirst = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.show_year_first);
    enableSeconds = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.enable_seconds);
    limitTimes = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.limit_times);
    limitDates = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.limit_dates);
    highlightDates = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.highlight_dates);

    // check if picker mode is specified in Style.xml
    modeDarkTime.setChecked(Utils.isDarkTheme(getContext(), modeDarkTime.isChecked()));
    modeDarkDate.setChecked(Utils.isDarkTheme(getContext(), modeDarkDate.isChecked()));


    // Show a timepicker when the timeButton is clicked
    timeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog tpd = com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.time.TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    Calendar.this,
                    now.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                    now.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE),
                    mode24Hours.isChecked()
            );
            tpd.setThemeDark(modeDarkTime.isChecked());
            tpd.vibrate(vibrateTime.isChecked());
            tpd.dismissOnPause(dismissTime.isChecked());
            tpd.enableSeconds(enableSeconds.isChecked());
            if (modeCustomAccentTime.isChecked()) {
                tpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
            }
            if (titleTime.isChecked()) {
                tpd.setTitle("TimePicker Title");
            }
            if (limitTimes.isChecked()) {
                tpd.setTimeInterval(2, 5, 10);
            }
            tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                }
            });

            //aqui da el error
              tpd.show(new Activity().getFragmentManager(),"Etiqueta" );

        }
    });



    // Show a datepicker when the dateButton is clicked
    dateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            java.util.Calendar now = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog dpd = com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                    Calendar.this,
                    now.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR),
                    now.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH),
                    now.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            );

            dpd.setThemeDark(modeDarkDate.isChecked());
            dpd.vibrate(vibrateDate.isChecked());
            dpd.dismissOnPause(dismissDate.isChecked());
            dpd.showYearPickerFirst(showYearFirst.isChecked());
            if (modeCustomAccentDate.isChecked()) {
                dpd.setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#9C27B0"));
            }
            if (titleDate.isChecked()) {
                dpd.setTitle("DatePicker Title");
            }
            if (limitDates.isChecked()) {
                java.util.Calendar[] dates = new java.util.Calendar[13];
                for(int i = -6; i <= 6; i++) {
                    java.util.Calendar date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                    date.add(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, i);
                    dates[i+6] = date;
                }
                dpd.setSelectableDays(dates);
            }
            if (highlightDates.isChecked()) {
                java.util.Calendar[] dates = new java.util.Calendar[13];
                for(int i = -6; i <= 6; i++) {
                    java.util.Calendar date = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                    date.add(java.util.Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, i);
                    dates[i+6] = date;
                }
                dpd.setHighlightedDays(dates);
            }




            dpd.show(new Activity().getFragmentManager(),"aasasdadada");


        }
    });


    return view;


}

@Override
public void onDateSet(com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(RadialPickerLayout view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por tu mensaje :

> llegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java

me parece que el problema es que estas creando una instancia de Activity, debes usar la actual, por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
dpd.show(new Activity().getFragmentManager(),"Etiqueta"); //INCORRECTO!
```

Usa unicamente `getFragmentManager()` si estas en un `Fragment` :

```
 dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Etiqueta"); // CORRECTO =)
```

No lo creo necesario pero si requieres del contexto por estar dentro de un `Fragment` usa el de la activity :

```
dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Etiqueta");
```

#### Actualizacion:

Revisando la documentacion de la libreria puedes ver un ejemplo:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
  MainActivity.this,
  now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
  now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad ... esta fue la solucion : dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Etiqueta");  ....
De verdad muy agradecido...

Comment: Que bien Eduardo me da gusto hayas solucionado tu problem, saludos!